# Не могу войти в backend yii2

Tags: yii2

Установил `yii2` `advanced`. Перехожу в админ часть, а там меня просят авторизоваться. Понимаю что вопрос глупейший, но так и не нагуглил, какой логин и пароль по умолчанию. `admin/admin` не подходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, где это можно посмотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все оказалось до глупости простым. Нужно было просто зарегестрироваться сначала с именем admin

Answer (score 2):

зайди в базу данных и поменяй пароль юзера

Comment: База данных хранит пароли в открытом виде!? О_о

Comment: В смысле? В коде нужно найти, где шифруется пароль и згенерить свой. При чем тут это?

Comment: `зайди в базу данных и поменяй пароль юзера` <- тут ни чего подобного не написано ;)

Comment: ну есть такое :) это же очевидно

Answer (score 0):

На frontend странице выберите SignUp и зарегистрируйте учетную запись.